# Where can I find the source code for the Javascript `typeof` operator?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I'm looking to see how the `typeof` operator in JavaScript knows that an object is a function.

To be precise, I'm wondering how I can take the function 'body' and reverse engineer it to determine what arguments it expects. The [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) property seemed close, but is only available within the evaluated function.

Neither `uneval()` or `toSource()` appear to do quite what I want, in addition to being obsolete.

Comment: I probably know just a fraction compared to you, but I would start looking at v8 source code on GitHub, I found this file that seems related to typeof operator: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/97cdf44d7c76ea3dce03ed72d4785775c0a848ea/src/objects-definitions.h

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator *Object (implements [[Call]])  "function"*

Comment: You can use `myFunction.toString()` and parse the results.  You can probably get the names of the arguments in most cases, but I don't see what any of this has to do with `typeof`.

Comment: @CristopherRosales I overlooked that when I was search, will take a look

Comment: @connexo I saw something similar on MDN. I don't understand what `(implements [[Call]]) ` means though.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm ok with doing that as a last resort, I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @connexo (pointing me at the spec (which I couldn't find) helped. I think https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects will point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) shows that:

Objects that do not implement `[[Call]]` are `object`s

Objects that do implement `[[Call]]` are `function`s

(`[[Call]]` is an "internal property" of objects - it's not exposed directly to interactable running JavaScript)

So anything that can be `()`d is a `function`. This will even include Proxies, since proxies can be called as if they were functions.

For the other question:

> I'm wondering how I can take the function 'body' and reverse engineer it to determine what arguments it expects

The simplest method would be to turn the function into a string and use a regex to parse the parameter list:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const argList = String(sum).match(/\((.*)\)/)[1];
console.log(argList.split(/,\s*/)); // depending on how complicated the list is
    // you may need to make the above pattern more elaborate
```

Comment: How can I programmatically check if an object can be `()`ed?

Comment: I'd just use `typeof`. If you don't want to use that, for the vast majority of cases, you could also check to see if the object inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question of how `typeof` works :-/

Comment: It works by checking to see if the object has an internal `[[Call]]` method. That's it, really, there isn't anything else to it. For the edge cases, it might not be possible to check in JS without actually trying to invoke the object to see what happens, since the proxy handler isn't available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385561/how-to-get-proxys-handler-from-proxy-object

Comment: He could probably also use `instanceof Function`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Afaik the only "object" not inheriting from `Object.prototype` is `null`.

Comment: Oops, typo, meant `Function.prototype`

Comment: I think "more elaborate" is an understatement when you factor in default parameters, spread syntax, and the possibilities of comments and newlines.  You might be headed toward a full-fledged parser.

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to be absolutely thoroughly accurate, it would require quite a lot of code, since theoretically even the whole script could be included in the parameter list if a dev felt like screwing with people.